# mkdir -p returns error if exists

Tags: shell-script, raspbian, loop-device, mkdir

Raspbian Stretch Lite:

```
$ mkdir --help
Usage: mkdir [OPTION]... DIRECTORY...
Create the DIRECTORY(ies), if they do not already exist.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -m, --mode=MODE   set file mode (as in chmod), not a=rwx - umask
  -p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
  -v, --verbose     print a message for each created directory
  -Z                   set SELinux security context of each created directory
                         to the default type
      --context[=CTX]  like -Z, or if CTX is specified then set the SELinux
                         or SMACK security context to CTX
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

in a script I write:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/target/home/user/resources
```

where `/mnt/target/home/user/resources` may exists.
If this is the case, the script will stop with this error:

> mkdir: cannot create directory "/mnt/target/home/user/resources": file exists

But the man page says if it exists it should not return error!

### UPDATE

There is no `resources` file present:

```
$ ls -la /mnt/target/home/user/
totale 13
drwxr-xr-x 4 mark      mark      1024 gen 10 16:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root      root      1024 gen 10 16:56 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark      mark       220 nov 13 14:09 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark      mark      3523 nov 13 14:09 .bashrc
drwxr-xr-x 3 root      root      1024 gen 10 16:56 bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 mark      mark       675 nov 13 14:09 .profile
drwxr-xr-x 2 root      root      4096 gen  1  1970 resources
```

### UPDATE2

Here the surrounding code in the script:

```
losetup -P /dev/loop0 image.img
e2fsck -f /dev/loop0p2
resize2fs /dev/loop0p2
mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p3
e2fsck -f /dev/loop0p3
mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/loop0p4

mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt/target

cd /mnt/target/home/
tar cf home.tgz user/
rm -r user/

mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt/target/boot/
mount /dev/loop0p3 /mnt/target/home/

tar xf home.tgz -C /mnt/target/home/

#mkdir -p /mnt/target/home/user/resources
mount /dev/loop0p4 /mnt/target/home/user/resources
```

`image.img` contains 4 partitions.

Comment: Is the already-present `resources` a _file_ and not a _directory_?  `mkdir -p foo` will not return an error if the _directory_ `foo` already exists, but if there is already a _file_ `foo`, that is an error condition.

Comment: `resources` is a directory, see the update in the question

Comment: I don't think so. `losetup` is involved instead. What information I might provide further to help you?

Comment: Are you running this as `mark` or `root`?

Comment: I'm running the script as `root`

Comment: Yep, it prints out `"Yes. It really is a directory."`

Comment: Yes, as @Christopher says, show the surrounding code.  I have a feeling that you may have multiple `mkdir` calls in there.

Comment: The errors and output look half Italian. Are you translating the messages before posting? Run `export LC_ALL=C` and run the command again to get the canonical, unlocalized error messages

Comment: What is a "broken mount point"? I searched with Google but I cannot find anything relevant

Comment: If my answer doesn't help you, run `strace mkdir -p /mnt/target/home/user/resources` and post the output. And be sure to post the **exact**, copy-pasted script that you're running and the exact, copy-pasted trace: if you've adapted the script in any way the problem may not be present in your adapted script.

Answer (score 3):

```
mount /dev/loop0p2 /mnt/target
cd /mnt/target/home/
mount /dev/loop0p3 /mnt/target/home/
mkdir -p /mnt/target/home/user/resources
```

You're invoking `mkdir` with the working directory set to `/home` on `/dev/loop0p2`. That working directory was formerly accessible at the path `/mnt/target/home`, but is now hidden behind the mount point for `/dev/loop0p3`. When you invoke `mkdir`, the path `/mnt/target/home` refers to the directory `/` on `/dev/loop0p3`.

I don't see why `mkdir` would care about its working directory, but this looks strange. If you've simplified your script before showing it in your question, the problem you're having may well be due to a confusion due to a directory that is hidden behind a mount point.

So try `cd`'ing out of `/mnt/target/home` before mounting it. Or don't use `cd` at all and use the `-C` option for the `tar` call and an absolute path for `rm`.

As a general rule, avoid mounting something to a directory that's in use in any way. The target directory should be empty and should not be the working directory of any process. The operating system will do the right thing, but what it considers the right thing may be surprising and in any case this can confuse humans and software.

Comment: The script is not simplified, I just left out the creation of partitions using `fdisk` because I might use an already existing image. Trying to mount to another direction, i.e. `/resources` seems to work, but I would like to have under `/home/user/`.